# How to programmatically bring up the on-screen keyboard on iOS when an HID keyboard is connected?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on an iOS application that interacts with external HID (Human Interface Device) keyboards. When a physical HID keyboard is connected to the iPhone, the on-screen keyboard is automatically suppressed, which is the expected behavior. However, I would like to provide users with the option to manually bring up the on-screen keyboard when needed, even when an external keyboard is connected.

I noticed that pressing the eject key on the external keyboard brings up the on-screen keyboard temporarily. Is there any way to achieve this programmatically within my iOS app?

I have explored various UIKit and UIResponder methods, but so far, I haven't found a solution that allows me to explicitly trigger the on-screen keyboard to appear. I understand that Apple generally discourages such behavior for security reasons, but our app's use case requires this functionality to enhance user experience in specific situations.

If there are any known workarounds or private APIs that can accomplish this task, I'd appreciate any insights or guidance on how to implement it safely and effectively. Additionally, if there are any alternative approaches that comply with Apple's guidelines and achieve the same objective, I'm open to exploring those options as well.

Thank you in advance for your help!